# Make 2 background images equal

Tags: css, image, image-scaling

I have 2 background images that I need to be vertically equal between each other like in this version
 [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5LP7.png)

Right now I have the styling set at as:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x, repeat-y;
background-position: 925px center;
```

However, the equality for the images only stays when I'm looking at on this viewport. When I exited out of the inspect tool, it messes up and resizes it.

I have tried calc() and other background-positions but I haven't been able to solve it.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do the trick. The reason the first background is applied to the body is so that when the number of pixels in width are odd, there won't be a white line in the middle.

```css
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body{
   background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/fjords.jpg);
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
#right{
   background: url(https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/img_lights.jpg);
   width: 50%;
   position: absolute;
   right: 0px;
   height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="right"></div>
```

ref.
https://css-tricks.com/multiple-backgrounds-left-half-and-right-half/

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this by having two containers, put each image in a separate container or as a background (which is better) and use flex. Much easier with less code . Check this guide https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/